# Return matching rows using sub-query to create list in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

I'm brand new to learning SQL. I have a very basic understanding of the language.

I have two tables. Storage Data is the table I ultimately want to return by [ScenarioID].

My second table, Storage Static, also has [ScenarioID], but I also need to first filter this table by two other fields [Platform] and [AccountID]. I have the following code that successfully filters this Storage Static table.

```
select
[ScenarioID]
from [dbo].[Storage Static]
WHERE [Platform] = 'ABC' AND [AccountID] in (select MAX([AccountID]) 
from [dbo].[Storage Static])
```

What I'm trying to do is basically embed the above code as a sub-query into my query for the original table Storage Data.

```
select
[ScenarioID],
[CountryID]
from [dbo].[Storage Data] t1
INNER JOIN
(
select
[ScenarioID]
from [dbo].[Storage Static]
WHERE [Platform] = 'ABC' AND [AccountID] in (select MAX([AccountID]) MaxPop
from [dbo].[Storage Static])  
) t2
on t1.[ScenarioID] = t2.MaxPop
```

I know the MaxPop part doesn't really work but that was my attempt at assigning a name or variable to that sub-query.

Ultimately, I want to filter my original table by the list of [ScenarioID]'s that I created in the sub-query.

Comment: Tag the only DBMS that you are really using.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just need to fix the `JOIN` conditions.

```
select sd.[ScenarioID], sd.[CountryID]
from [dbo].[Storage Data] sd join
     (select [ScenarioID]
      from [dbo].[Storage Static]
      where [Platform] = 'ABC' and
            [AccountID] in (select max([AccountID]) from [dbo].[Storage Static])
     ) ss
     on sd.[ScenarioID] = ss.[ScenarioID]
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! Have to work on my logic ordering

Answer (score 0):

Since you need `MaxPop` to be taken as a field needed for `join'
instead of`in`clause, I use an`inner join`, so that the filed can be considered for the join.

```
select  t1.[ScenarioID], t1.[CountryID]
from [dbo].[Storage Data] t1
INNER JOIN
(
    select [ScenarioID], MaxPop
    from [dbo].[Storage Static] s
    Inner Join 
    (select MAX([AccountID]) MaxPop
     from [dbo].[Storage Static])  m 
        on m.MaxPop = s.[AccountID]
    WHERE [Platform] = 'ABC' 
) t2
on t1.[ScenarioID] = t2.MaxPop
```